# Data Base Migration from Btrieve (6.15 for WIN 95) to Oracle/Postgre?

Tags: database, database-migration, btrieve

I'm doing a kind of experiment for which i need Btrieve (not Pervasive SQL/PSQL) DataBase files (db tables). I have Googled a lot but didn't find any db files, any help guys? The basic requirement is to migrate the Btrieve DB to Oracle/Postgre DB.

can someone provide me DB files or link to DB files?
for example: a sample project which uses Btrieve DB

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I specially install Delphi and Titan Btrieve components to extract data from btrieve tables.

In Titan Btrieve Manager (can't remember name) you must create connection (specify folder with files) and then use it in Delphi components of Titan Btrieve.

Can't provide files but i think you can use this component to create tables.

Answer (score 0):

First off, Btrieve files and Pervasive SQL / PSQL files are the same.  Second, most data files are going to have proprietary data in them so having people send you files will probably not happen.
If you have a Btrieve / Pervasive PSQL engine, which you need to read data files, then you can create a program to create data files and fill them with random data.

Also, there are some sample data files included with the engines in a DEMODATA directory.

Comment: i am unsure but doesn't Btrieve use .btr files and PSQL uses .ddl & .mkd?

Comment: A Btrieve / PSQL data file can have any extension.  I've seen .BTR, ,MKD, .DB, .DAT, and even files with no extension.  No extension caused problems in later versions but worked in Btrieve v5.